# Validating File Path w/Spaces in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, winforms

I'm something of a n00b at C# and I'm having trouble finding an answer to this, so if it's already been answered somewhere feel free to laugh at me (provided you also share the solution). :)

I'm reading an XML file into a GUI form, where certain elements are paths to files that are entered into TextBox objects.  I'm looping through the controls on the form, and for each file path in each TextBox (lol there's like 20 of them on this form), I want to use File.Exists() to ensure it's a valid file.

The problem with this is that the file path can potentially contain spaces, and can potentially be valid; however File.Exists() is telling me it's invalid, based entirely on the spaces.  Obviously I can't hard-code them and do something like

`if (File.Exists(@"c:\Path To Stuff"))`

and I tried surrounding the path with ", like

`if (File.Exists("\"" + contentsOfTextBox + "\""))`

but that didn't make a difference.  Is there some way to do this?  Can I escape the spaces somehow?

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Can you print out the path that you are actually passing to Exists, and validate that the file exists as entered?

Comment: Yup, I can print out the paths just fine, after they've been read in from the XML.  The files are definitely there.

Answer (score 4):

File.Exists works just fine with spaces.  There is something else giving you a problem I'll wager.

Make sure your XML reader isn't failing to read the filename (parts of XML do not allow spaces and some readers will throw an exception if they encounter one).

Comment: So when File.Exist() returns false, I've got a MessageBox popping up with the full file path that apparently doesn't exist.  The XML reader is reading in the filenames just fine.  Also, I'm able to fill my TextBox objects with the filenames from the XML, and they're fine too; it's just this validation that's causing the problem.  Good thinking though. :\

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? Make sure you're using Directory.Exists if you expect a folder name.

Comment: I just saw your reply lower.  The only other thing I can think of is your permissions settings.  From the docs:

If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.

Answer (score 4):

> > @"c:\Path To Stuff"

The above could be a *directory* **not** a *file*!

Hence you would want to use Directory.Exists!

> > @"c:\Path To Stuff\file.txt"

If you did have a file on the end of the path then you would use File.Exists!

Comment: Actually, "Path To Stuff" _could_ be a file and not a directory. It's pretty rare to have a file without an extension, but it's permissible in every file system I've ever used (and I've used quite a few).

Comment: Thanks Gregory; yeah that was a bad example on my part, lol.  It's really c:\Path To Stuff\file.txt.  I guess my brain wishes it were still in UNIX-land where there typically aren't file extensions :)

Answer (score 2):

As the answer said, File.Exists works with spaces, if you are checking for existence of a Directory however, you should be using Directory.Exists

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact error that you get when `File.Exists` says it is invalid?

I *suspect* that you are passing a path to a directory and not a file, which will return false. If so, to check the presence of a directory, use [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To echo Ron Warholic: make sure the process has permissions over the target folder. I just ran into the same "bug" and it turned out to be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to replace \ with \\ ?

Comment: `@"c:\Path To Stuff"` is a verbatim string and doesn't require you to escape backslashes.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: He's not using that syntax in the second example.

Comment: He's not using the syntax but the "\" will not be escape characters as they are already in a variable.

Comment: The 2nd example is really what I'm dealing with.  I tried doing a replace of "\" with "\\"; the replace was fine but it didn't make a difference.  Do I have to do anything like replace C:\ with C:/?

Comment: Also, the debugger shows me that C# already replaced \ with \\.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use youtStringValue.Trim() to remove spaces leading/trailing, and Replace to remove spaces in the string you do not want.

Also, rather use System.IO.Path.Combine rather to combine these strings.

Comment: File.Exists trims the trailing spaces for you. And how would removing spaces using Replace help, as that would end up with something like C:\ProgramFiles\... which would not exist?

Comment: If from the textbox, the user entered spaces that was not intended, it can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

hi this is not difficult if you can convert the name of the path to a string array then go through one by one and remove the spaces

once that is done just write() to the screen where you have the files, if it is xml then your xmlmapper will suffice

file.exists() should only be used in certain circumstances if you know that it does exist but not when there can be space chars or any other possible user input

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ on string variables:

```
string aPath = "c:\Path To Stuff\text.txt";
File.Exists(@aPath);
```

That should solve any escape character problems because I don't think this really looks like the spaces being the problem.